# Error con jquery y librerias que usan jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo una web en la que usos varias librerias que usan jquery:

- nyroModal
- timepicker
- cleditor
- ...

El problema es que derrepente han dejado de funcionar, y analizando la consola del navegador me aparece esto:

> ```
> TypeError: $(...).nyroModal is not a function[Saber más] index.php:190:3
> TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function[Saber más] index.php:1591:4
> TypeError: $.widget is not a function[Saber más] jquery.ui.spinner.js:19:1
> TypeError: $.ui is undefined[Saber más] jquery.ui.datetimepicker.js:26:1
> TypeError: $.timepicker is undefined[Saber más] script.js:542:4
> TypeError: $.browser is undefined[Saber más] jquery.maskedinput.js:8:6
> TypeError: $.browser is undefined[Saber más] jquery.cleditor.js:156:3
> TypeError: $(...).not(...).checkbox is not a function[Saber más] script.js:842:4
> TypeError: "$(...).dialog is not a function"
> ```

Es como si hubiera dejado de funcionar la librería de `Jquery`.

La libreria la llamo asi:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.8.2.js"><\/script>')</script>
<!-- Do the same with jQuery UI -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery.ui || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-ui-1.9.1.js"><\/script>')</script>

<!-- Do the same with Lo-Dash.js -->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/0.8.2/lodash.js"></script>
<script>window._ || document.write('<script src="js/libs/lo-dash.js"><\/script>')</script>
<!--<![endif]-->
<!-- IE8 doesn't like lodash -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore.js"></script><![endif]-->

<!-- Do the same with require.js -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.0.6/require.js"></script>
<script>window.require || document.write('<script src="js/libs/require-2.0.6.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nyroModal.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nyroModal.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('.nyroModal').nyroModal();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Parece que está cargando la librería antes que el script de jQuery. Asegurate de que el primer script que se cargue sea jQuery y que el resto se carguen en cascada si existe alguna dependencia entre ellas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. El script de jquery está el primero en la linea y debajo todos los demas

Comment: Mira en las herramientas de desarrollador (F12) qué scripts se han cargado y cuáles no.

Comment: se cargan todos @Kiko_L

Comment: Necesitas agregar más código para que podamos reproducir el problema en la pregunta, haría falta ver cómo cargas el resto de bibliotecas/plugins. Si antes funcionaba, es raro que deje de funcionar, puede ser algo temporal (p.e. Un fallo en el cdn) o algo que se haya añadido nuevo (p.e. Una biblioteca que cree conflicto con las otras). Por lo general, un programa que funcionaba sin problemas no deja de funcionar sin más. Lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve].

Comment: ¿Tu página se sirve en http o por https?

Comment: es http @AlvaroMontoro no se ha añadido ningun script nuevo

Comment: he añadido mas codigo @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: En españa ha habido un problema y se han caido todos los dominios `.es` ppuede que sea por eso? Mi dominio es `.com` @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: Si ese fuera el problema, en la consola de errores te debería aparecer un error 404 indicando que los ficheros no pudieron cargarse y después los errores que compartes. ¿Seguro que no hay nada en el log de errores antes de lo que compartes? ¿Si vas a la pestaña de tráfico, ves algún problema ahí?

Answer (score 1):

Me da la impresión de que estás sobrecomplicando las cosas usando el método `window.variable || document.write(...)`. Primero prueba usando el contenido de los CDN antes de poner esos fallback.

El siguiente ejemplo me funcionó sin problemas (tuve que usar una versión del plugin que encontré en un sitio cualquiera con https)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/0.8.2/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.0.6/require.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.artofliving.org/sites/all/libraries/jquery.nyroModal/styles/nyroModal.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script  src="https://www.artofliving.org/sites/all/libraries/jquery.nyroModal/js/jquery.nyroModal.custom.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2e/HTTPS_Everywhere_logo.jpg" class="nyroModal" title="3rd Street Promenade">Pínchame para ver una imagen</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { $('.nyroModal').nyroModal(); });

</script>
```

Ahora, veo que estás pidiendo `require.js`. Esa librería es precisamente para cargar tus dependencias en orden estableciendo cuál depende de cuál. Podrías requerir los plugins de jquery estableciendo que primero debe estar cargado jQuery